# SharePoint Framework Extension doesn't show placeholder

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I have followed the sample of Microsoft regarding create SPFx Extension. Everything worked well until I deploy it to the site.

After deployed the app into App Catalog, I could see the feature is activated on the destination site but there is no top/bottom placeholder show up in the modern UI.

I checked the console but found no issue as well:
[image]

The weird thing is if I debug using the browser (Chrome) I can see that the break point at variable declaration is hit (const LOG_SOURCE) but the override onInit function is not hit.

Thanks,

Comment: which link did you follow ?

Comment: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension this one. Until part 3 as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed when they release the GA version. That's all

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a first release tenant? Extensions moved to RC0 about a month ago, but is still not considered production ready.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Release-Notes---Extensions-RC-Drop-1.2

Comment: Yes I have First Release Tenant. And The site I'm using to test is Developer Site template as well. Because I could successfully test them in debug mode (where the files are served from local gulp), but it doesn't work when I'm deploy them to the site itself and host the files using CDN/local

Comment: Maybe it isn't rolled out to your tenant yet. Just to be sure, have you seen the changes introduced in the RC? (https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/changes-between-dev-preview-and-rc)

Comment: Yes I have seen the changes. I guess it's working in debug mode not in the deployment mode yet. I'll wait untill Sep 29 for more information then. I believe it will be GA on this MS Ignite. Thanks anyway